# Why is my conditional formatting not working properly in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting, calculated-field

I am trying to add conditional formatting into my table and although it works for some of the data, about half of it is not returning any value for the condition.

```
    Condition = MAXX('2020 PNRs', 
   IF('2020 PNRs'[2020-2021] <=1, 1,
        IF('2020 PNRs'[2020-2021] <=10000 , 2,
            IF('2020 PNRs'[2020-2021] >10000 , 3))))
```

2020-2021 is a calculated measure

```
2020-2021 = 
SUM('TTV'[2020TTV]) + SUM('TTV'[2021TTV])
```

but it is quite simple so I am not sure if that has anything to do with why it's not working?

[image: Here you can see where it works for some and not others]

Comment: can you show the initial table completely?? I'm not sure where this TTV[2020TTV] and TTV[2021TTV] come from.

Answer (score 1):

Your Condition formula filters '2020 PNRs' table. It might be that the top part of your screenshot presents results that are not available on '2020 PNRs', but are rather sourced from some other table (e.g. '2021 PNRs'?). It would be good for us to understand the source of your table and your data model.

In the meantime, I suggest testing the following measure:

```
Condition =
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        [2020-2021], 1,
        [2020-2021] <=10000, 2,
        [2020-2021] >10000, 3
    )
```

If this still doesn't work, then return the value of [2020-2021] measure as the last argument to understand the issue:

```
Condition =
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        [2020-2021], 1,
        [2020-2021] <=10000, 2,
        [2020-2021] >10000, 3,
        [2020-2021]
    )
```